# Nexcloud + Reverse proxy ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when trying to access my subdomain

Tags: docker, redirect, docker-compose, subdomain

In order to host multiple websites I'am trying to reproduce the following schema
[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqiHV.png)

The redirection works correctly with the following sites and without having to indicate the port: https://git.domain.tld and https://portainer.domain.tld
but does not work for: https://test.domain.tld (The page is not redirected correctly => I'm getting this ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

here is my docker-compose :

```
version: '2'
services:
  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: proxy
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy: "true"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./uploadsize.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/uploadsize.conf:ro
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - "default"
      - "proxy-tier"
  
  proxy-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: letsencrypt
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER=proxy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    volumes_from:
      - "proxy"
    depends_on:
      - "proxy"
    networks:
      - "default"
      - "proxy-tier" 
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    container_name: portainer
    restart: always
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=portainer.domain.tld
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=portainer.domain.tld
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=xxxxx@xxxx.xxx
      - LETSENCRYPT_TEST=false
    volumes:
      - ./portainer/:/data
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - "default"
      - "proxy-tier"

  gitea:
    image: gitea/gitea:latest
    container_name: gitea
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=git.domain.tld
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=git.domain.tld
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=xxxx@xxxx.xxx
      - LETSENCRYPT_TEST=false
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=3000
      - ROOT_URL=https://git.domain.tld
      - DOMAIN=git.domain.tld
      - PROTOCOL=http
      - USER_UID=1000
      - USER_GID=1000
      - POSTGRES_USER=xxxxx
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
      - POSTGRESS_DB=xxxxx
    volumes:
      - ./gitea:/data
    ports:
      - "9001:3000"
      - "9002:22"
    networks:
      - "default"
      - "proxy-tier"
  nextcloud:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/nextcloud
    container_name: drive
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/Paris
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=test.domain.tld
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=test.domain.tld
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.xxx
      - LETSENCRYPT_TEST=true
      - DEBUG=true
    ports:
      - "9005:443"
      - "9006:80"
    volumes:
      - ./drive/appdata:/config
      - ./drive/data:/data
    networks:
      - "default"
      - "proxy-tier"
    restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  certs:
  vhost.d:
  html:
  nextcloud:
  db:
networks:
  proxy-tier:
```

Thank you in advance for your help, I've been stuck on this problem for a few days

EDIT :

Some lines from proxy logs when I enter test.domain.tld:

```
 nginx.1     | test.domain.tld 91.182.X.X - - [28/Apr/2022:04:21:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 301 162 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0" "172.29.0.6:80"


 nginx.1     | test.domain.tld 91.182.X.X - - [28/Apr/2022:04:21:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 301 162 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0" "172.28.0.3:80"


 nginx.1     | test.domain.tld 91.182.X.X - - [28/Apr/2022:04:21:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 301 162 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0" "172.29.0.6:80"
```

...

AND this is from nexcloud :

```
Exception: Not installed in /config/www/nextcloud/lib/base.php:277
Stack trace:
#0 /config/www/nextcloud/lib/base.php(649): OC::checkInstalled()
#1 /config/www/nextcloud/lib/base.php(1087): OC::init()
#2 /config/www/nextcloud/cron.php(43): require_once('/config /www/nex...')

}

Exception: Not installed in /config/www/nextcloud/lib/base.php:277
Stack trace:
#0 /config/www/nextcloud/lib/base.php(649): OC::checkInstalled()
#1 /config/www/nextcloud/lib/base.php(1087): OC::init()
#2 /config/www/nextcloud/cron.php(43): require_once('/config/www/nex...')

}

Exception: Not installed in /config/www/nextcloud/lib/base.php:277
Stack trace:
#0 /config/www/nextcloud/lib/base.php(649): OC::checkInstalled()
#1 /config/www/nextcloud/lib/base.php(1087): OC::init()
#2 /config/www/nextcloud/cron.php(43): require_once('/config/www/nex...')

} 
...
```

And this is my ngnix config /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
    # test.domain.tld                                                    
    upstream test.domain.tld {                                           
        # Exposed ports: [{   443 9005 tcp 0.0.0.0} {   80 9006 tcp 0.0.0.0}]  
        # Default virtual port: 80                                             
        # VIRTUAL_PORT: <no value>                                             
        ## Can be connected with "proxy_default" network                       
        # drive                                                                
        server 172.28.0.3:80;                                                  
        # Cannot connect to network 'proxy_proxy-tier' of this container       
        # Cannot connect to network 'proxy_default' of this container          
        ## Can be connected with "proxy_proxy-tier" network                    
        # drive                                                                
        server 172.29.0.6:80;                                                  
    }                                                                      
    server {                                                                       
        server_name test.domain.tld;                                         
        listen 80 ;                                                            
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;                            
        # Do not HTTPS redirect Let'sEncrypt ACME challenge                    
        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {                             
            auth_basic off;                                                
            auth_request off;                                              
            allow all;                                                     
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;                                    
            try_files $uri =404;                                           
            break;                                                         
       }                                                                      
       location / {                                                           
           return 301 https://$host$request_uri;                          
       }                                                                      
    }                                                                              
    server {                                                                       
       server_name test.domain.tld;                                         
       listen 443 ssl http2 ;                                                 
       access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;                            
       ssl_session_timeout 5m;                                                
       ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;                                      
       ssl_session_tickets off;                                               
       ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/test.domain.tld.crt;                
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/test.domain.tld.key;            
       ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/test.domain.tld.dhparam.pem;            
       ssl_stapling on;                                                       
       ssl_stapling_verify on;                                                
       ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/test.domain.tld.chain.pem;  
       add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;        
       include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default;                                    
       location / {                                                                   
            proxy_pass http://test.domain.tld;                           
       }                                                                              
    }
```

Comment: I'm still stuck, anyone have an idea please ...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the question itself - yes, it is possible and you already doing it.

You say the page `test.domain.tld` is not redirected correctly - what exactly happens?

Without knowing what happens exactly with the redirection when you enter the `test.domain.tld`, I would suggest some experiments with the `nextcloud` image, but in the first place I would ensure if in the exact configuration you have, there is no typo in the `VIRTUAL_HOST` environment variable. In the example it looks good, but in the actual compose file you use there might be a typo that would cause it to fail.
The other services work, so the `nextcloud` setup might need something yet to work with `nginx-proxy`.

Comment: When I enter test.domain.tld I get this ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and there is no typo in the VIRTUAL_HOST variable

Comment: can you check the logs from the `proxy` and the `nextcloud` container? it might be there is an issue between these two that needs to be addressed